# Why does Laravel Fortify send a redirect on an API Request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

I´m using Laravel (10) **Fortify** (with Sanctum), to authenticate requests to the REST API. It works quite well but I´ve **one serious issue** and I think it´s simply a configuration problem:

**Whenever an API request on a Fortify route fails** (e.g. send a login request when the user is already logged in), Laravel (Fortify) **tries to redirect the client** to a defined route (e.g. home) as would it be a classic web request. However, that should normally not happen, when it´s an API request with "Accept: application/json" header in my understanding. In that case I would expect a http status matching the issue as a response but no redirect header.

Comment: Can you try modifying `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in that modify `render` method to provide JSON responses for specific exceptions. Also you can use a middleware which can check the API requests and modify the responses accordingly

Comment: Sorry and to answer your question actually i believe Fortify is not specifically tailored for API authentication and maybe that's why it behaves as it would for a web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally there are two possible solutions:**

**1. Update RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware as suggested by @Zenix**

```
if(!$request->wantsJson()){
    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

**2. Setup own API routes for fortify and don´t include the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware**

```
// Login
// "guest" Middleware (alias for RedirectIfAuthenticated) not enabled on API routes
    // cause it redirects to the login page, which is not what we want for API routes
    $limiter = config('fortify.limiters.login');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
      ->middleware(
        [
          //'guest:' . config('fortify.guard'),
          $limiter ? 'throttle:' . $limiter : null
        ]
      );
```

In my opinion Option 1 is the better way to go cause it resolves the issue on the basis. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2):

Fortify by default uses the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware, you can disable it by commenting the line `return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);` or adding a "if" statement:

```
if(!$request->wantsJson()){
    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```